# Flash - Air app tests fine but publishes broken

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I have an issue with an air desktop app I'm working on currently. When I test the movie within flash, it all works the way it's supposed to, but when I publish it for Air desktop as an exe executable, install and run it, it acts as if there is absolutely no AS3 at all... I have no idea what is going on here.

Anybody have any idea what could be happening?

Files- https://www.mediafire.com/?ai45gcam69ganxa

Comment: Did you check your "Included files" area of the AIR settings to make sure you've included all needed external files?

Comment: I can't believe I screwed that up. I added something later on and forgot to include the xml file for it.... Thanks SCCOTTT